# Creating Helper in laravel? mycodetest

Tags: php, laravel, helper

Here is my code it is working but i want best practice. Any suggestions?

Composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files":[
        "app/Helper/Commonfunctions.php"
    ]
},
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it :)

Comment: In my Laravel projects I also use this way, when you have too many Helpers, you could just declare an entrypoint and from there include all the rest of the files, but in the end it is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think best way is add helper folder, but in your case I do this:

```
    "autoload": {
       "classmap": [
           "database/seeds",
           "database/factories",
           "helpers"
       ],
       "psr-4": {
           "App\\": "app/"
       }
   },
```

If you have 20 helpers, will you add 20 lines to composer.json?

Comment: Does this still work if your helper file is just a collection of global functions?

Comment: what do your mean? global functions? create helpers.php and require in index.php

Comment: According to [Composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap), the classmap "is built by _scanning for classes_ in all .php and .inc files in the given directories/files." That would suggest that your helpers would need to be in PHP classes. But if your helpers are just a bunch of global functions (like Laravel's) you can do this without editing index.php by using the `files` array instead of `classmap` in your `composer.json`